# Send email with attach file WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to send an email with a log file from my windows phone 8.1 app. I found this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732263/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-a-winrt-windows-store-application) :

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=recipient@example.com&subject=The subject of an email&body=Hello from a Windows 8 Metro app."); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

Is there a special parameter to specify the attach file or another completly different way ?

Comment: I used the DataTransferManager to prepare the content and then let the user choose an email app, I succeed to set the title of the mail : `request.Data.Properties.Title = loger.GetFileName();` but not the destination. Any help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [EmailMessage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.aspx) for this. A sample code can look like this:

```
private async void SendBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage { Subject = "Sending test file" };
    email.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("myMailbox@mail.com"));

    // Create a sample file to send
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("testFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Something inside a file");

    email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file.Name, file)); // add attachment
    await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email); // send email
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I though it was not possible to use those classes... I read the Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace since it just says that "The functionality described in this topic is not available to all Windows and Windows Phone apps. For your code... etc"

Comment: The accepted answer will not attach email to any win32 email application such as Outlook.  attaching to email will only work with Windows Mail app-store app